# How do I change a CheckboxListTile's title after a specific event?

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I've gotten stuck trying to get this to work, basically I have a ListView with two CheckBoxListTiles inside it, when a user selects a CheckBoxListTile a modal pops up with a DatePicker, what I want to achieve is after the user selects the date, the CheckBoxListTile text (or title I guess) gets changed to the date, here is my code so far.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;

class ChecklistWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChecklistWidget createState() => _ChecklistWidget();
}

class _ChecklistWidget extends State<ChecklistWidget> {
    String date1 = "";
    String date2 = "";
    Map<String, bool> values = {
    'Choose a specific date': false,
    'Choose an alternative date': false,
  };
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext build){

    return new ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: values.keys.map((String key) {
          return new CheckboxListTile(
            title: new Text(key),
            value: values[key],
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                values[key] = value;
                showCupertinoModalPopup(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) { return _buildDatePicker(
                    CupertinoDatePicker(
                        mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
                        initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                        onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
                           // date1 = newDateTime.toString();
                            print("Your Selected Date: ${newDateTime.day}");


                        },
                    ),
                    ); });
              });
              title: date1;
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
      );

  }

   Widget _buildDatePicker(Widget picker){
    return Container(
      height: 216.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
      color: CupertinoColors.white,
      child: DefaultTextStyle(   style: const TextStyle(
                color: CupertinoColors.black,
                fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
                child: GestureDetector(
                // Blocks taps from propagating to the modal sheet and popping.
                onTap: () {},
                child: SafeArea(
                    top: false,
                    child: picker,
                ),
                ),)
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm new to flutter so I'm sure I'm just missing something, but I cant wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you don't loop over the map keys because you have a limited amount of dates so it's better to just build each date and update its value accordingly.

If you did actually have an unknown number of dates it's better to store each one in a model with a `label`, `value` and `enabled` fields.

But this is enough for your case:

```
class _ChecklistWidget extends State<ChecklistWidget> {
  String date1;
  String date2;
  bool specificDateEnabled = false;
  bool alternativeDateEnabled = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext build) {
    return new ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: [
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text(date1 ?? 'Choose a specific date'),
        value: specificDateEnabled,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            specificDateEnabled = value;
            showCupertinoModalPopup(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return _buildDatePicker(
                    CupertinoDatePicker(
                      mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
                      initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                      onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
                        setState(() {
                          date1 = newDateTime.toString();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                });
          });
        },
      ),
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text(date2 ?? 'Choose an alternative date'),
        value: alternativeDateEnabled,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            alternativeDateEnabled = value;
            showCupertinoModalPopup(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return _buildDatePicker(
                    CupertinoDatePicker(
                      mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
                      initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                      onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
                        setState(() {
                          date2 = newDateTime.toString();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                });
          });
        },
      ),
    ]);
  }

   Widget _buildDatePicker(Widget picker){
    return Container(
      height: 216.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
      color: CupertinoColors.white,
      child: DefaultTextStyle(   style: const TextStyle(
                color: CupertinoColors.black,
                fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
                child: GestureDetector(
                // Blocks taps from propagating to the modal sheet and popping.
                onTap: () {},
                child: SafeArea(
                    top: false,
                    child: picker,
                ),
                ),)
    );
  }
}
```